# What's a polite way of confirming if a position offered is official?

Tags: research-undergraduate, communication

I'm an undergrad student, and I intend to start assisting a senior PhD student with her research work. I'm really interested in the work (definitely don't want to let go of this opportunity), but I'm unsure if the *position being offered to me* is **official**, i.e. if I would be a *research assistant* or something, so to speak.

I was told by the PhD that if I'm to accept, she will have to seek permission from her PI / keep the PI in the loop - which makes me feel that it's probably official but I'm not sure.

**What's a polite way of asking for the necessary clarifications?**

Comment: What do you mean by "official"? That you are paid? That you have an official title? That you get a contract?  And are you asking about the *offer* being official (i.e. formal), or is it about the job itself?

Comment: So she has offered an **internship** and you want to know whether you will be allowed to write **intern** on your resume?

Comment: @Stef No one mentioned "intern"? Why do you bring it up in bold?

Comment: This should be closed as "individual circumstances."  The way universities go about hiring research assistants varies a great deal.  But in most cases PhD students are not allowed to perform hiring.

Comment: @user151413 By official, I mean if I can mention it on my CV, i.e. official title is the closest among the options you've given.

Comment: @Stef That's exactly right. The word *internship* wasn't mentioned anywhere though!

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I think the fact that the PhD student says that she needs to keep her PI in the loop/bring it to the PI's attention implies that the PhD student can't perform hiring. What do you think?

Comment: Seems like the key consideration is whether the _professor_ (_not_ the grad student) is open to writing a letter of recommendation for you (assuming all goes well). If you don't get a letter, don't get paid, and don't get course credit, then I'm not sure why you would want to pursue this position. Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: You can mention any activity that you've been involved in on your CV. Are you actually clear whether it's a position (which implies that there will be a job contract, a job title and payment) or you're asked to conduct voluntary work? Both could be listed on your CV.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Whatever you do, you can mention it on your CV.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I'm unsure if it will be paid/unpaid (doesn't matter to me either). Is that something I should be concerned about, though? Sounds like voluntary work to me so far. Working in an *official capacity* (voluntary still) might help in my efforts being acknowledged.

Comment: If it's not paid, then there's no position. Did the grad student ever use the word "position"? In case of unpaid work, there's no strict sense of "official" or "non-official" and, probably, no person who reads your CV will care if the voluntary work was official or non-official. You can still get some official recognition, for instance, by being named on the lab page.

Comment: The crucial form of academic recognition you can draw from voluntary work is authorship of the resulting papers. You can surely ask if you're going to be involved as an author in the papers resulting from the work. This is the norm, but still, asking is absolutely OK, and the expected answer is "yes". (In fact, any other answer should be a dealbreaker.)

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I was told I'd be a co-author! So that sounds great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was told by the PhD that if I'm to accept, she will have to seek permission from her PI / keep the PI in the loop - which makes me feel that it's probably official but I'm not sure.

The PhD student likely has no authority nor budget to hire you. They're trying to establish whether you'd take a position if formally offered. If you will, they'll go and get permission/money from their PI. Whether the PI will hire you depends on the PhD student's sway with the PI and on the PI's budget.

> What's a polite way of asking for the necessary clarifications?

**TL;DR**: Say, *I'm interested, how do we proceed*?

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually know what "official" means. If your institution has some definitions for such things then it makes sense, but people can't normally just make up titles for things. They can, of course, provide letters in which things are described informally using words that sound like titles. But "official" depends on some institutional backing.

But the way to learn is just to ask, not worrying much about "polite". Will you have a title of some kind that you can use on your CV? That is the question you want answered, and if, no, ask how you can/should present it on the CV.

But you are wise to want to have it clarified. Even if it isn't "official" it can be a good thing  on the CV.

Comment: *"I was wondering if I would be assisting you in an official capacity, and whether or not I could mention this activity on my CV in the future."* Does that sound about right?

Comment: Also, I must mention, that this project is **not** based at my institution. Do you think that changes anything? Are there any additional clarifications I should make?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Your proposed wording is fine but imho unnecessary. Unless something shady is going on, I would simply assume the answer is "yes"  and instead ask if the PhD student's PI will provide a reference letter. I assume being payed is not on the table.

Answer (score 1):

**Be prepared to ask for what you want.**

It might be that the PhD student had in mind an informal relationship. But if you would like some formal title or recognition, then the PhD student might be happy to try to arrange it for you.

**Consider looking within your own university for recognition.**

The PhD student might not know how to accommodate such a request. PhD students, and often even professors, don't necessarily spend a lot of time thinking about formal titles or "how the bureaucracy works".

Universities tend to offer formal recognition to their own students for a variety of activities. You might see if there is a suitable such program at your own university, which allows for an external supervisor, and ask the PhD student if she would be willing to serve in that role. Potentially, it might look good on her CV too.